# Heatmap generation in Python using different heat intensity

Tags: python, matplotlib, heatmap

I am trying to generate a Hit map of a scatter plot using matplotlib's hist2d. Can I change the heat level intensity for that? I looks like heat color gets changes linearly. I want to do it exponentially? Is there any other tool in python other than matplotlib's hist2d that I can use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you probably want to use [color normalization](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.0/tutorials/colors/colormapnorms.html#power-law)

Comment: Thank you. This is what I was looking for. It worked!!